# with ExpressJS and TypeScript what is the proper syntax to retrieve query parameters?

Tags: typescript, express

using TypeScript `3.5`, `express` at `4.17` and `@types/express` at `4.17`, what is the proper syntax to access *query* parameters?
We started projects several years back and it was pretty simple. Inside our handlers:

```js
function getSomething(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const { context, name } = req.query;
    // call something with a string parameter
    doSomethinWithStrings(context, name);
}
```

Now we are finally upgrading some to TS `3.x` but with better TS type checking and newer definitions for `express`, we're getting errors:

```
Argument of type 'string | Query | (string | Query)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

We tried declaring some global interface (all our queries require a context for example). But using the `as` syntax, it still complains:

```js
// ~/definitions.d.ts
interface CtxQuery {
    context: string;
    name: string;
}

// handler.ts
...
    const { context, name } = req.query as CtxQuery;
```

It then complains about possible incompatible types:

```
Conversion of type 'Query' to type 'CtxQuery' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'Query' is missing the following properties from type 'CtxQuery': context, name
```

We can quiet that latter warning by using a `type` instead of `interface`. But it still does seem like a lot of work for something that used to be so simple. What am I missing?

Yes, we can solve all of this by using `as any` but that's not correct. We are using `express-validator` so, we know the shape of the data (at least as much as we need/can)

**update**

As a quick workaround, I created a `safeQuery<T>()` generic method that works pretty slick:

```
import { Request } from 'express';

export function safeQuery<T extends string>(q: Request): { [k in T]: string } {
    return q.query as any;
}
```

When used with the object destructuring, it's seamless:

```
const { context, name} = safeQuery(req);
doSomethinWithStrings(context, name); // works like a charm, context and name are strings
```

Comment: Why not just doing `const { context, name } = req.query as { [key: string]: string}`?
I don't really get the point of using that "generic" (extending string?) method

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73089957/9406951 answer your question?