# How to type `request.query` in express using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, express, url, types, request

I'm running an `express.js` application using TypeScript.
Every time I try to process `request.query.foo` I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Setup:

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

function getHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const { query } = request;

  query.foo; // string | QueryString.ParsedQs | string[] | QueryString.ParsedQs[] | undefined

}

router.route('/')
  .get(getHandler)
```

Is there a proper way to type `request.query` without casting?

Comment: It already has the right type; it's telling you that `query.foo` might be undefined and *that's true*.

Comment: True, but how would I solve the following?

`if (query.foo) { parseInt(foo, 10) } `

This would still resolve in

`Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'ParsedQs' is not assignable to type 'string'`

Comment: Well that's all true, isn't it? You've only ruled out undefined, it's still not certain to be parseable as an integer. If you have extra information, like it will definitely only ever be a string, you can provide it to the compiler as a [*type assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions): `parseInt(foo as string, 10)`.

Comment: Yes, I also came up with this solution.
I would prefer to not use any casting if possible.
I've seen `Request` is a Generic which can be enhanced but I would like to only type `request.query` and leave everything else like `request.body` and `request.params` as is

Comment: Then *deal with those other possible cases*. Look at e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types. Overriding the query type won't change the runtime behaviour (it *can't*, types and TS don't exist at runtime).

Comment: I already tried to use TypeGuards but even this does not work
`function isNumber(num: any): num is number { return Number.isInteger(num); }`.
It still returns in `Type 'ParsedQs & number' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: It's not clear how you're using that, but also *why* - none of the options you're trying to narrow from is that it's already a number, you're trying to check if it's a string *before* trying to parse it.

Comment: @marcobiedermann - Check the type as you extract a field from query. `const foo = typeof query.foo === "string" ? query.foo : "";` After this, foo is guaranteed to be a string and only a string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Definition

The `Request` is a generic which accepts additional definitions:

```js
interface Request<
  P = core.ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = core.Query,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {}
```

Source: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/89a4f41af507e68daf5f4794ad257f48920275f2/types/express/index.d.ts#L113-L118

#### Example

```js
interface RequestParams {}

interface ResponseBody {}

interface RequestBody {}

interface RequestQuery {
  foo: string;
}

function getHandler(
  request: Request<RequestParams, ResponseBody, RequestBody, RequestQuery>,
  response: Response
) {
  const { query } = request;

  query.foo; // string
}
```

Comment: You really helped me a lot. It's not mentioned anywhere, google did not help either. 

Answer (score 50):

The solution is to use generics in the following manner.

```
const router = Router();

interface Foo {
    foo: string;
}

function getHandler(request: Request<{}, {}, {}, Foo>, response: Response) {
  const { query } = request;

  query.foo;

}

router.route('/')
  .get(getHandler)
```

Comment: Have you tested this? I'm trying to use this approach and getting the error: `Type 'Request' is not generic.`

Comment: Tested on @types/express 4.17.11. Works great!
BTW, it would be better to use `Request<unknown, unknown, unknown, Foo>`. Otherwise, the ESLint will give error: Don't use `{}` as a type. `{}` actually means "any non-nullish value".

Comment: Or `const getHandler: RequestHandler<unknown, unknown, unknown, Foo> = (req, res) => { ... }`

Comment: For anyone else who reads my comment and wonders...it turns out I had not imported `Request` from the Express types, and so Fetch type of Request was being used.

Comment: This only works for the query object. How would I do this for the params and body objects?

Comment: Similar to @HongboMiao, I arrived at a similar ESLint complaint, but believe that instead of using `unknown` for each, wouldn't `Record<string, unknown>` be better as these should always be objects, right?

Comment: If you get `Type 'Request' is not generic.` add `import type { Request } from "express";`

Comment: it's a good practice to make params such as `foo?: string` optional, since they may not be present.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the `foo` name generic so I don't have to create an interface for every single route?

Answer (score 13):

I like to use the following approach in my projects.

```
  const { url } = req.query;
  
  if (typeof url !== "string") {
    throw new ServerError("Query param 'url' has to be of type string", 400);
  }
```

After checking the type TypeScript won't complain any more for this scope.

Comment: This is a good approach. Handles types well, and is nice and simple

Answer (score 5):

you can do it like this :-

```
interface Query {
   param1:string;
   param2:string;
};

function getHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {
   const {param1,param2} = request.query as unknown as Query;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I would like to avoid type casting

Comment: Every time you use "as" you basically override the type system, so you should only use it as a last resort. It's a good way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Use the new "satisfies" instead if you can. But it doesn't help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of tricking typescript, you should be validating your incoming data with actual JS.

If you are only interested in handling `foo` when it's a string, then validate that it's a string as you extract it from `query`.

```
function getHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {
    const { query } = request;

    const foo = (typeof query.foo === "string") ? query.foo : "";

    // Want to error check?
    if (foo === "") {
        // Handle missing foo
    }

    // You now have a guaranteed string that typescript recognizes as a string

    const myNumber = parseInt(foo); // No warnings here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use, which seems to be compatible with strict/recommended TS settings:

```
import type { Request } from "express";

type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>;

export type RequestWithBody<T> = Request<
  EmptyObject,
  EmptyObject,
  T,
  EmptyObject
>;

export type RequestWithQuery<T> = Request<
  EmptyObject,
  EmptyObject,
  EmptyObject,
  T
>;
```

And then something like:

```
export async function somethingPost(
  req: RequestWithBody<Payload>,
  res: Response
) {
...
}
```

I don't know how to type the Response properly. If I use `Response<SomethingResponse | string>` my function seems to be strict about the json return values, but express doesn't accept it as an argument to post().

The `| string` is because I either successfully return the response or return an error code with a string message in the body.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion the simpler and straight forward method is to use the `StringConstructor`. Any downside of this method in this particular situation is welcome in the comments.

> var String: StringConstructor
> (value?: any) => string
> Allows manipulation and formatting of text strings and determination and location of substrings within strings.

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

function getHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {
  const { foo } = request.query;

  String(foo) // string
}

router.route('/').get(getHandler)
```

Comment: If you convert an object to a string, you will get "[object Object]" and if you convert an array to a string you will get coma-separated values. You should handle these edge cases, either by not handling the request or by sending a bad request error to the client when the query parameters are not formatted the way you expect

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

```
import { Request, Response, Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

interface HandlerRequest extends Request {
    query: {
        foo: string
    }
}

function getHandler(request: HandlerRequest, response: Response) {
  const {query: {foo}} = request;

  if (foo) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Otherwise...
  }       
}

router.route('/')
  .get(getHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this and discovered that express depends on [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs), which supports non-standard query string formats like arbitrarily nested arrays and objects.

This is why we are forced to handle cases where `request.query.foo` is something other than `string | undefined`: they could actually happen.

The correct course of action is to either ignore the request or let the client know that it's malformed. I saw a lot of answers recommending to simply turn off type checking. This is truly bad advice. You should always investigate whether an error could actually happen at runtime before silencing a type error. It's what TS is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```js
// express.interface.ts

import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

interface RequestParams {}

interface ResponseBody {}

interface RequestBody {}

interface RequestQuery {
  /* Add custom parameters to use like `req.query.id` */
  id?: string
}

interface ResponseBody {}

export interface CustomRequest<P = RequestParams, ResBody = ResponseBody, ReqBody = RequestBody, Q = RequestQuery>
  extends Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, Q> {}

export interface CustomResponse<ResBody = ResponseBody> extends Response<ResBody> {}

export interface CustomNextFunction extends NextFunction {}
```

Add proper function or parameters on each interfaces. Also you could add custom functions in each `CustomRequest`, `CustomResponse`, `CustomNextFunction` like error handling.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is to use [Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion):

```
function getHandler(request: Request, response: Response) {

  const foo: string = request.query.foo as string

  //do something with foo ...

}
```

Answer (score -2):

The best solution for me was to first cast as unknown, and then my custom interface.

```
interface CustomReqQuery {
   foo: string;
   bar: string;
}

function getHandler(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const { foo, bar } = req.query as unknown as CustomReqQuery;

  ...
}
```

Comment: This could backfire. You should handle or drop bad requests, not cheese the compiler.