# Create wrapper function to reorder generic parameters in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to come up with an answer to [How to type `request.query` in express using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63538665/how-to-type-request-query-in-express-using-typescript) because I want one, myself.

In `express`, using [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) the route parameters get inferred correctly.  However, express has no way of specifying a strong type for its query string parameters without specifying the route template parameters directly, which means specifying *all* of them.

The `RouteMatcher`'s declaration is:

```ts
export interface IRouterMatcher<
    T,
    Method extends 'all' | 'get' | 'post' | 'put' | 'delete' | 'patch' | 'options' | 'head' = any
> {
    <
        Route extends string,
        P = RouteParameters<Route>,
        ResBody = any,
        ReqBody = any,
        ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
        Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
    >(
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-unnecessary-generics (it's used as the default type parameter for P)
        path: Route,
        // tslint:disable-next-line no-unnecessary-generics (This generic is meant to be passed explicitly.)
        ...handlers: Array<RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>>
    ): T;
    //...
}
```

I would like to create an identity wrapper function, `withQS`, that will let me specify the `ReqQuery` parameter alone and infer the remaining template types.

```ts
const withQS = <
  ReqQuery extends QueryString.ParsedQS,
  /* TODO */
>(path: /* TODO */, ...handlers: /* TODO */): /* TODO */ =>
  [ path, ...handlers ];

app.get(...withQs<{ foo: 'bar' | 'baz' }>(
  ('some/:route/:param', (req, res, next) => {
    const { foo } = req.query;
    // knows foo is 'bar' or 'baz'
    const { route, param } = req.params;
    // knows that route and param are the only properties
  }
);
```

An alternative would be to have `withQS` wrap each handler, but that's less desirable.

Ideas?  [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gSygCwIoGUYF4YB4BQMMGMApgB5SlgAmEMACgIYBOEpNGANITAEogArlTKVqdGNBYIwAc2ySo0uTyIAZEMCYAbejiZgAnqpgAJAzW2k2oqrXoBBFiyaHc52lZa5mLgLYQACIIwFAI4KxuAsKkAHxcxOgJGlq6sbEKTi5uHpbWPqxMAcGh4WCRuNFU8YnJmjoQ6fixABS8LEJUAFz8naQJvAB0w8gWXhA9ueP4AJQ9ANpV-TDDg1PWEAC62Bm88x0xCaujnhubANz4+LKkUG1Eq4goGLgA3jAAjhMwAOQAZiAQD8YAAfX4AI1YwIAvq0fl0AUCEixSB8djBXrwiKBICArINtCBZC0UR9Bh9BNZDOSIDNLkQiAB6RkwAACUAgAFoKAAHUihbnOEAsLEwUnkyksalfBQ-cHaJjIH6XUXMtkc7nkPkC6wdEUMmA4iB40gEokk1ESqmDRGQlh0q4Go0ms3E8U8woBG2Ah0GtXsrm8-lQQV60XO-GEt2Wj3+CCDO2+mDQmazFU3O5DYZPNDoN6fb7-QHAsFyqGgiEKpXnGC21g9KQyWTzbawlrwxGMrp2n7I1HozFO8DGyPm8UU61fJNEceS6V6SuK5Xh4cuqMWskTqXekCJlVD3Gj6Nk2NFeOI6eG1dHjeDU9eve8FNpq5-QRgUrgGAZghEJa2cR6EbFReBICg7AkXx2E4TAcCgjhuBgNUUFIGAoEMPl4FQuADFgKAQBgHlhFrBA2FgHNOjFVFBFIptFA6ORtEMNCMLo0gADcqRQNjdFIXgUgaBQDEMZoST6HoliOEYxg2HoslcdwZO8XwzxKMIIilSo+hqRCBLSWIZgxaErjVPT6BoUg-hkJAyggfB0MwlTihCdTyk0-9wMA+i6JwYDZAyHBeA8sR7F+BFixgAB+DFa0BBslDo6EYC6IK+gA0KO0BLseyimLEXi5RZBrO0CsS5Kgv5YUaFwPyEj82J6RgfAZCoFg-iYYBUL4ajSGgHwFCcoIXLKSIEjAkLINYaCSDgqaEKSGAzKEowMkHQjPW+BhGq3QwegwRrCVSb4zMuYz7Iw1D4JghRutAFhqtq7y5ArPyWwrMBBD8cFrArcFASsAx3sEbRtArd8LKssAOAaq4HNQ9ZlI2gaNrUkapTGzBPNCq6ZsYOaYLqI7lsMALeA3CSer6waMcJhoDPRdiQAQGhziAA)

Comment: Since this isn't tagged with `express` I assume we shouldn't need dependencies on it to answer the question.  If so, please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w2EZ4W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.  If not, maybe we should put the `express` tag on it?

Comment: Nah, this is purely a TS question.  When I have time (tomorrow evening likely), I'll throw together a TS Playground and let you know when I have.  I typed this all out on my phone, or I would have done so already.

Comment: @jcalz Done!  Hopefully it's minimal enough.

Comment: Are you asking about partial type parameter inference as requested in [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)?  If so then you need a workaround like currying ([see this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPxlEW)).  If not then could you elaborate more?